# Run JUnit test on Android device after first install

Tags: android, testing, junit

Is it a good idea to run once jUnit test on clients device after first install?

It's not only unit tests (I can test them localy) but mostly resource allocations, rooted check,etc.

**If app will now work correctly I would like to display message and send info to me, before allowing user to interact with buggy app.**
Because this app will run mostly on low end smartphones I expect some difficulties.

I would like hear form experienced app makers how you deal to make your app run on every phone.

Comment: IMO no it isn't. JUnits are only for developing purposes. If you want todo some checks you could use Assert's directly in your business code. I knew a lot of applications using Assert this way...

Comment: @StefanBeike I'm not familiar with other test frameworks than jUnit. Could you recommend one?